# Joomla user profile update not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

On my local web-server everything works fine.
But on the live server it does not work.
The website is 1:1 the same.

**My problem is:** when I click save profile, it stores in my database into the table:`user_profiles` the following entries:

`user_id    key value   ordering`
`78 profile.address1    ""  1`
`78 profile.address2    ""  2`
`78 profile.city    ""  3`
`78 profile.region  ""  4`
`78 profile.country ""  5`
`78 profile.postal_code ""  6`
`78 profile.phone   ""  7`
`78 profile.website ""  8`
`78 profile.favoritebook    ""  9`
`78 profile.aboutme ""  10`
`78 profile.dob ""  11`

the problem here is, that `profile.dob  ""` is not a valid date string, which will create an other error and of course it does not look very nice to have then written in your profile `""`.
On my local server, if the user did not enter any values, it will also not write anything into the table `user_profiles`.

I have tries to find the piece of code that is responsible for all that, but it looks like almost impossible to find the right spot.

how can I get rid of this ?

Comment: Are you running the latest Joomla! 2.5 version?

Comment: add your php code which is responsible for the above action

Comment: yes latest joomla 2.5... @Dasun: if I knew where it does that only.. I was now looking for hours to find out but can find the php code...

Answer (score 0):

The profile_value column in #__user_profiles is a varchar, so it can't store dates in MySQL format.

Depending on how you display that info, you need

If the field is empty ("") by default Joomla should display the message "No Information Entered " in the profile page.

Comment: #__user_profiles is a varchar, so it can't store dates <-- wrong. you can store date in a varchar but it's not suitable

Comment: yes I know it should display "No Information Entered" but instead it will display "", I guess it only says "No Information Entered" if in the table #__user_profiles are no entries... as soon as there is an entry it will try to display this... also when it displays "" and I save again, it will store "\"\"" to my database... which will be displayed as "\"\""... so it seems every time it wants to save to my database it surounds with an ""...

Comment: Your files / db structure may be corrupted. What is the history of the website? Any upgrades from versions below 2.5?

Comment: in fact yes... the website has been done an upgrade from 1.5 -> 2.5, but I do not actually know how it was done, since I did not have time myself, a freelancer did it for me...

Comment: Ok. Than check this out: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-fix-database-issues-in-joomla-25

Comment: Also override core component with the latest version.

Comment: hmm ok this "fix" database tool is releasing a new error "Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::getBasename()", I will see if it works with the core component override...

Comment: Do you have a PHP version smaller than 5.2.2? Joomla recommends 5.3 + and the absolute minimum is 5.2.4 +

Comment: ohh maybe it is just because of the php version... on the live server I have php version: PHP Version 5.2.0-8+etch16 and on the local: 5.3.15

Comment: That's quite a difference and 5.2.0 is NOT supported by Joomla!